# Função recursiva para relacionar um array com outro

Tags: php

Meu problema é o seguinte. Possuo duas tabelas no meu banco de dados, pacientes e doenças.

Tabela pacientes possuem as colunas nomedopaciente, (sintoma 1, sintoma 2,....sintoma n). Os sintomas são alimentados com o valores entre 0 e 1. Pois são valores de lógica fuzzy.

A Tabela Doenças é uma base de conhecimentos, onde possuem os campos doencaNome,(sintoma 1, sintoma 2,....sintoma n). Os sintomas são alimentados com o valores entre 0 e 1. Pois são valores de lógica fuzzy.

É necessário realizar uma varredura nessas duas tabelas, e gerar uma nova em seguida.

Exemplo: Relação entre tabela pacientes(nomedopaciente, sintoma 1) x tabela doenças (doençaNome, sintoma1). Dessa relação é necessário pegar o menor valor. Ou seja. Se  (nomedopaciente, sintoma 1) = 1 e (doençaNome, sintoma1) = 0,45. O valor retornado da verificação será 0,45.

Com o código abaixo consigo fazer isso, mais preciso aplicar a recursividade, e não usar for,s fora de uma função recursiva.

```
//Pega repete a analise somente para o paciente corrente, ou seja 1.
for ($p=0; $p < 1; $p++) { 
    //Inicializa o arrey.
    $_max = array();
    //Pega todas as doenças registradas no banco para análise.
    for ($d = 0; $d < count($doencas); $d++) {
        //Inicializa o arrey.
        $_min = array();
        //Pega todos os sitomas registrados no banco para análise.
        for ($i=1; $i < count($sintomas)+1; $i++) { 
            //Cria um array com as relações (sintomas x doença) e (sintomas x paciente), e gera o valor mínimo de cada uma.
            array_push($_min, min($doencas[$d]['ap'.$i],$pacientes[$p]['ap'.$i]));      
        }
    //Recebe o valor mínimo da relação, para cada doença.
    $valor = max($_min);
    //Gera um array com o valor máximo, da relação dos mínimos.
    array_push($_max, $valor.' - '.$doencas[$d]['profissao']);

    };
};
```

Comment: Tem que ser no PHP ? Não pode ser o select ou uma view já trazendo no formato que precisa ?

Comment: Se o problema é o for não pode ser foreach ?